# Scala Passing Function with Argument

Tags: scala, functional-programming

The Scala example for passing a function to another function lacks the case where the passed function (timeFlies) takes an argument (x).

```
object Timer {
  def oncePerSecond(callback: (Int) => Unit) {
    while (true) { callback(x); Thread sleep 1000 }
  }
  def timeFlies(x: int) {
    println("time flies like an arrow...")
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    oncePerSecond(timeFlies(5))
  }
}
```

How can I make the above code work?

Edit: I added an x in the oncepersecond to clarify the goal is to pass the integer.

Comment: Do you *really* need to pass the Int to `oncePerSecond`? All the answers below should be fine and are better than passing that Int. Anyways, `oncePerSecond(timeFlies, 5)` and `def oncePerSecond(callback: Int => Unit, x: Int)` should work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are at least two ways you can do it, depending on where exactly you want to pass the argument in.  The first way is where you keep `main` like you had it.

```
object Timer {
  def oncePerSecond(callback: => Unit) {
    while (true) { callback; Thread sleep 1000 }
  }
  def timeFlies(x: Int) {
    println("time flies like an arrow...")
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    oncePerSecond(timeFlies(5))
  }
}
```

The other method is to pass the parameter in at the point of the callback, like this:

```
object Timer {
  def oncePerSecond(callback: (Int) => Unit) {
    val x = 5
    while (true) { callback(x); Thread sleep 1000 }
  }
  def timeFlies(x: Int) {
    println("time flies like an arrow...")
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    oncePerSecond(timeFlies)
  }
}
```

Note that `timeFlies` has the signature `(Int) => Unit`, but `timeFlies(5)` has the signature `=> Unit`, because of [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).  This basically means you can apply the parameter to automatically create a function that takes fewer parameters.  `oncePerSecond` needs to know in its signature if you've already applied the `Int` parameter to the callback or not.

Both methods are useful for different use cases.  The first way lets `oncePerSecond` not have to know about the callback's parameters.  The second way lets you change the value of `x` every time through the loop if you want.

Comment: Model answer. Thank you.

Comment: in the first way 'callback: => Unit' is there anyway to preserve the 'type' of the function I want to pass? `callback: => Unit` is so general, I would like to say exactly which type of function i'm expecting...

Comment: Nope.  The whole point of using that method would be if you don't want to know the unapplied type.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `timeFlies` will be `Unit`, not `Function`. Perhaps you meant:

```
oncePerSecond(() => timeFlies(5))
```

Answer (score 2):

`oncePerSecond(() => timeFlies(5))`

or

`def oncePerSecond(callback: => Unit) {...`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `callback: () => Unit` is a zero-parameter function that returns `Unit`. You should make it call-by-name parameter (something that evaluates to `Unit`):

```
def oncePerSecond(callback: => Unit) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the function as an argument

```
def function1(callback: Int => Unit): Unit = {
  // do something
}

def callback_function(x: Int): Unit = {
   // do something
}

function1(callback_function)
```

If you want to pass reference of the function to a variable you can do the following...

let say we have function..

```
def handleLogic(x: Int): Unit => {
   // do something
}

val method = handleLogic _
```

or

```
val method = handleLogic(_)
```