# Ask pattern in actor hierarchy requires similar things at each level?

Tags: scala, akka

My Actor hierarchy for `Monitoring` looks like

```
    Monitor
    /     \
  Disk    Memory
         /      \
      Remote   Local
```

Where `Monitor` asks its children actors to get the data and so on. 
In the end Monitor receive all the data and prints it on console (for example).

Considering only `Memory` Hierarchy, I realized that in `ask` pattern, the call in hierarchy looked like

**(at Memory level)**

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  lpMemory <- (lpMemory ? CollectLPMemoryStat).mapTo[MemoryInformation]
```

**(at Remote Level)**

```
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  import context.dispatcher
  (remoteActor ? HealthReportRequest).mapTo[MemoryInformation].pipeTo(sender)
```

So at every level in `ask` pattern, I needed to do 4 things

1. Import `ExecutionContext`
2. Specify the `Timeout`
3. Transform the output `mapTo[MemeoryInformation]`
4. send back to sender `pipeTo(sender)`

This gets cumbersome if there are more hierarchies.

Since I am new to `Akka` and `Scala` stack, I am looking to ideas where I can make this code much better

Thanks

Comment: Should work without the `mapTo` in between.

Comment: You mean only the lowest level should set it?

Comment: Only the highest. Where you actually need the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do, to cut the overhead a bit:

1. Extract the timeout in a separate trait and mix it in to the actors. All in all, the actors are classes as any other, the OOP principles still stick to it. I would define the import `ExecutionContext` and specify the timeout into it.

   ```
   import akka.util.Timeout
   import scala.concurrent.duration._

   trait AskEnabled {
       implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
       implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
   }
   ```

The implicit `ec` value is a bit of a hack, since I learned during the writing of this answer that the imports from the traits are actually not propagated. So, this may be slightly disputable, in case one day the framework does not expect `ec` but `execContext` for example, but in general keeps the code clean.

Anyway, the actor looks like:

```
class Actor1 extends Actor with AskEnabled {

val actor2 = context.actorOf(Props[Actor2])

override def receive: Receive = {
 case "send" => {
   val responseFuture = (actor2 ? "request").mapTo[String]
   responseFuture.onSuccess {
     case response: String => println(response)
   }
  }
 }
}
```

2. I believe there is no need to both map and then pipe at the Remote Level, piping it directly should work well. The return type of the `?` is a `Future[Any]`, however it is only upcasted to `Any`, you don't actually lose the type information when shuffling it around. It's more from Scala's type inference thing rather than Akka. However the upcast is something Akka does, where the whole type safety thing gets blurry, at least until TypedActors become more popular, I suppose.

   `(remoteActor ? HealthReportRequest).pipeTo(sender)`
3. If you have more a greater hierarchy in which you are reusing some functionality, then use the functional nature of Scala, extract that method (somewhere) and pass it to each actor. Functions are a first class citizen and you can pass them in the constructor, avoiding repeating yourself. This is a rough idea, you can also try mixing it in into a `trait`. Take a look at: [Scala Passing Function with Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433384/scala-passing-function-with-argument) .

Comment: I think you should create `trait AskEnabledActor extends Actor` and then `implicit val ec = context.dispatcher` in order to use the actor systems dispatch rather than the global one. then `class Actor1 extends AskEnabledActor`

Comment: True, that would also be completely valid. I just proposed this for a bit more transparency.

Comment: Thank you so much @AleksandarStojadinovic and matttinbits, your help is very much appreciated. I learned something new and cleaned up the codebase further. Thank you again